# Сайт неправильно отображается на IOS и не работают некоторые функции

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, webp

Есть сайт `site.ru`
На андройде и обычном ПК переключение в ночной режим работает нормально, а так же картинки  на сайте отображаются. На ios (Safari) ни картинки, ни ночной режим и фон на верху не работают. Подскажите как исправить?
По картинкам подгружаю их так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" async>
    window.onload = function() {
        let images = [...document.getElementsByTagName("img")];
        for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].classList.add("lazyload");
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://site.ru/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://site.ru/js/lazysizes.min.js" async></script>
  <img src="https://site.ru/image/samolet_p.webp" data-src="https://site.ru/image/samolet_p.webp" style="float: left;padding-top: 8px;padding-right: 5px;" class="lazyload"> 
   </body>
```

Имеется параллельно .jpg версия изображения под тем же именем, но грузим webp для облегчения страницы сайта.

Второе по поводу ночного режима он вот так на сайте прописан

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const table = document.getElementById('table');
const target = document.getElementById('target');
document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', '#FFFFFF');
document.body.style.setProperty('--glav-color', '#09406f');
container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    target.classList.toggle('toggle');
    target.classList.toggle('sun');
    target.classList.toggle('moon');

    if (getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--main-color') == '#FFFFFF') {
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-color', 'none');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-fontColor', 'beige');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--table-color', '#000000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--glav-color', '#1C293E');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--h2-fontColor', '#fff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', '#231C36');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tbody-fontColor', '#FFAE46');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tdhover-fontColor', '#fff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--trhover-fontColor', '#fff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--blackwhite-fontColor', '#fff');

    } else if (getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--main-color') == '#231C36') {
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--responsiv-color', '#ffffff');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tbody-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--glav-color', '#09406f');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--h2-fontColor', '#030303!important');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--table-color', '#FFFFFF');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', '#FFFFFF');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--tdhover-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--trhover-fontColor', '#000');
        document.body.style.setProperty('--blackwhite-fontColor', '#000');
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {--main-color: #FFFFFF;--table-color: #FFFFFF;width: 100%;justify-content: center;align-items: center;background-color: var(--main-color);transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;}.table-responsive h2 {color: var(--responsiv-fontColor)!important;}.table-responsive {background: var(--responsiv-color)!important;}#container {border-radius: 25px;height: 30px;width: 80px;background-color: var(--main-color);cursor: pointer;transition: all .3s ease-in-out;box-shadow: 0px 0px 15pxrgba(0, 0, 0, .15);margin: 0px auto;z-index: 999999;position: relative;top: 10px;}table {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}tbody {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}td:hover, tr:hover {color: var(--tdhover-fontColor)!important;}table.dataTable.display tr:hover {color: var(--blackwhite-fontColor)!important;}tr:hover .sorting_1:hover {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--trhover-fontColor);}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd: {var(--table-color)!important;color: var(--tbody-fontColor)!important;color: black!important;}#target {position: relative;left: 0px;transition: all .3s ease-in-out;bottom: 18px;}.toggle {left: calc(100% - 50px) !important;}.sun {cursor: pointer;width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFDB73;}.sun::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 30px;height: 30px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFDB73;}.sun::after {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 55px;height: 55px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFDB73;opacity: .3;}.table-responsive::after {background: #000!important;border-top: 1px solid#fff!important;color: white;width: 100%!important;}.moon {cursor: pointer;width: 50px;height: 50px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;position: relative;z-index: 999999999;}.moon::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 60px;height: 60px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;opacity: .5;}.moon::after {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 75px;height: 75px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;opacity: .3;}.moon > div {position: relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;}.moon > div::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 25px;height: 25px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #FFE4BF;z-index: 1;}.moon > div::after {content: '';position: absolute;top: 10px;right: 10px;width: 20px;height: 20px;border-radius: 50%;background-color: #0A515B;z-index: 2;}#zagolovok {color: var(--h2-fontColor);}.jumbotron {background-color: var(--glav-color);}#container::before {content: "";position: relative;left: 50px;width: 18px;height: 18px;display: block;background: url(/sun1.webp) no-repeat;top: 5px;right: 0px;z-index: 99999999;bottom: 0px;}#container::after {content: "\2606";position: relative;left: 10px;right: 50px;width: 12px;height: 20px;display: block;bottom: 75px;color: white;overflow: hidden;}.mewtwo-datepicker td {color: black!important;}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd: {var(--table-color)!important;color: var(--tbody-fontColor)!important;}table {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}tbody, tr {background-color: var(--table-color)!important;color: var(--tbody-fontColor)!important;}tr:hover {background-color: var(--table-color);color: var(--tbody-fontColor);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60" data-inited_widgets="324725293bb33b026edc45474cad4d87">
<div id='container'>
                <div id='target' class='sun'>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari не взаимодействует с `webp` в стандартной конфигурации.
Можно воспользоваться следующим вариантом.
При загрузке страницы проверять поддержку `webp` примерно таким образом:

```js
function hasWebP() {
    var rv = $.Deferred(), img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { rv.resolve(); };
    img.onerror = function() { rv.reject(); };
    img.src = "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp";
    return rv.promise();
}

hasWebP().then(function() {
    $('#x').text("Webp работает!!!.");
}, function() {
    $('#x').text("Браузер не поддерживает Webp, показать стандартную картинку png.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='x'></div>
```

И Уже в зависимости от этого, либо выводить картинку `webp`, если браузер поддерживает это, либо картинку в `png`, если нет.

Comment: Денис а как быть если названия изображений авиакомпаний формируются (беруться по апи) формируются php скриптом, но расширения можно любое хоть png?

Comment: @Arcadiy Уточните, пожалуйста, что Вы имеете ввиду? По сути, название не имеет значение, главное это сам формат файла. Вы можете на всякий случае добавить проверку уже  в `php`, если формат файла будет изначально в `webp`, то можете использовать стандартную функцию `imagecreatefromwebp`, чтобы сохранить копию картинки в обычном формате `jpg/png/jpeg` и так далее. По сути, если Вы используете данную технологию и есть необходимость подгружать все картинки, то храниться они у Вас должны в 2 экземплярах (обычная и `webp`).

Comment: Денис, изображения авиакомпаний у меня вот так формируются `https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2zEd/22giDkDv9`

Comment: @Arcadiy В этом случае, вы можете обрабатывать начала данные `$row['airline']` На текущий момент у Вас там просто ссылка. Вы получаете саму картинку где-то в другом месте. Там где её получаете - выделяйте сразу тип файла, и передавайте в данный файл уже скрепив таким образом, например '/image/123|img'. При получении данных в этом файле - разбиваете строку через explode и выводите полученные данные (ссылку отдельно, а тип файла проверяйте в зависимости от поддеркжи `webp` и если поддерживает - дописывайте `webp`, если нет, то берите типа файла после explode.

Comment: Например, передали Вы файл '/img/airline1|img'  в переменной `$row['airline']`. Далее пишите `$newRow = explode($row['airline']);` Проверяете поддержку `webp`, если поддерживается, то $newRow[1] = `webp`, если не поддерживается, то не меняем. А в image после проверки поддержки `webp` пишите так: `<img src="https://pics.avs.io/100/40/<?=$newRow[0]'.'$newRow[1] ?>"/>`

Comment: Немного не понимаю